# How to configure I2S with an external DAC?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, esp32, voice-recognition, i2s

I am building a bluetooth speaker that detects voice commands via microphone (using ESP32). The microphone is using I2S and an internal ADC. Then I have an external DAC to play music from bluetooth. i2s_num_0 is attached to the internal ADC. How do I connect i2s_num_1 to the external DAC? I tried replacing i2s_num_0 with i2s_num_1 in the following code, but it didn't work.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <driver/i2s.h>
#include <esp_task_wdt.h>
#include "I2SMicSampler.h"
#include "ADCSampler.h"
#include "config.h"
#include "CommandDetector.h"
#include "CommandProcessor.h"

// BT, config, discover, audio
#include "esp_bt_main.h"
#include "esp_bt_device.h"
#include "esp_gap_bt_api.h"
#include "esp_a2dp_api.h"
// audio DAC and amp config
#include "driver/i2s.h"

// callback (processes bt data)
void bt_data_cb(const uint8_t *data, uint32_t len){
   // number of 16 bit samples
   int n = len/2;
   
   // point to a 16bit sample 
   int16_t* data16=(int16_t*)data;
   
   // create a variable (potentially processed) that we'll pass via I2S 
   int16_t fy; 
   
   // Records number of bytes written via I2S
   size_t i2s_bytes_write = 0;

   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    // put the current sample in fy
    fy=*data16;
    
    //making this value larger will decrease the volume(Very simple DSP!). 
    fy/=1;
    
    // write data to I2S buffer 
    i2s_write(I2S_NUM_1, &fy, 2, &i2s_bytes_write,  10 );
    
    //move to next memory address housing 16 bit data 
    data16++;
   }
}

// i2s config for using the internal ADC
i2s_config_t adcI2SConfig = {
    .mode = (i2s_mode_t)(I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_RX | I2S_MODE_ADC_BUILT_IN),
    .sample_rate = 16000,
    .bits_per_sample = I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT,
    .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_ONLY_LEFT,
    .communication_format = I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S_LSB,
    .intr_alloc_flags = ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL1,
    .dma_buf_count = 4,
    .dma_buf_len = 64,
    .use_apll = false,
    .tx_desc_auto_clear = false,
    .fixed_mclk = 0};

// i2s config for using BT
i2s_config_t i2s_config = {
    .mode = static_cast<i2s_mode_t>(I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_TX),
    .sample_rate = 44100,
    .bits_per_sample = I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT,
    .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_RIGHT_LEFT,
    .communication_format = static_cast<i2s_comm_format_t>(I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S|I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S_MSB),
    .intr_alloc_flags = ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL1, // default interrupt priority
    .dma_buf_count = 8,
    .dma_buf_len = 1000,
    .use_apll = false,
    .tx_desc_auto_clear = true
};

// This task does all the heavy lifting for our application
void applicationTask(void *param)
{
  CommandDetector *commandDetector = static_cast<CommandDetector *>(param);

  const TickType_t xMaxBlockTime = pdMS_TO_TICKS(100);
  while (true)
  {
    // wait for some audio samples to arrive
    uint32_t ulNotificationValue = ulTaskNotifyTake(pdTRUE, xMaxBlockTime);
    if (ulNotificationValue > 0)
    {
      commandDetector->run();
    }
  }
}

void setup()
{
  // i2s pinout
  static const i2s_pin_config_t pin_config = {
    .bck_io_num = 26,//26
    .ws_io_num = 27,
    .data_out_num = 25, //
    .data_in_num = I2S_PIN_NO_CHANGE
  };

// now configure i2s with constructed pinout and config
  i2s_driver_install(I2S_NUM_1, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);
  i2s_set_pin(I2S_NUM_1, &pin_config);
  i2s_set_clk(I2S_NUM_1, 44100, I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT, I2S_CHANNEL_STEREO);
  i2s_set_sample_rates(I2S_NUM_1, 44100);
  
 // set up bluetooth classic via bluedroid
  btStart();
  esp_bluedroid_init();
  esp_bluedroid_enable();

 // set up device name
  const char *dev_name = "ESP_SPEAKER";
  esp_bt_dev_set_device_name(dev_name);

  // initialize A2DP sink and set the data callback(A2DP is bluetooth audio)
  esp_a2d_sink_register_data_callback(bt_data_cb);
  esp_a2d_sink_init();
  
  // set discoverable and connectable mode, wait to be connected
  esp_bt_gap_set_scan_mode(ESP_BT_SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE); 


  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Starting up");

  // make sure we don't get killed for our long running tasks
  esp_task_wdt_init(10, false);

  // start up the I2S input (from either an I2S microphone or Analogue microphone via the ADC)

#ifdef USE_I2S_MIC_INPUT
  // Direct i2s input from INMP441 or the SPH0645
  I2SSampler *i2s_sampler = new I2SMicSampler(i2s_mic_pins, false);
#else
  // Use the internal ADC
  I2SSampler *i2s_sampler = new ADCSampler(ADC_UNIT_1, ADC_MIC_CHANNEL);
#endif
  // the command processor
  CommandProcessor *command_processor = new CommandProcessor();

  // create our application
  CommandDetector *commandDetector = new CommandDetector(i2s_sampler, command_processor);

  // set up the i2s sample writer task
  TaskHandle_t applicationTaskHandle;
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(applicationTask, "Command Detect", 8192, commandDetector, 1, &applicationTaskHandle, 0);

  // start sampling from i2s device - use I2S_NUM_0 as that's the one that supports the internal ADC
//#ifdef USE_I2S_MIC_INPUT
//  i2s_sampler->start(I2S_NUM_1, i2sMemsConfigBothChannels, applicationTaskHandle);
// #else
  i2s_sampler->start(I2S_NUM_0, adcI2SConfig, applicationTaskHandle);
// #endif

}

void loop()
{
  vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
}
```

Comment: It would help more if you posted the code that *doesn't* work than the code that does work. Otherwise we're missing details on what you tried to do. What is the external DAC? How is it connected? If I were debugging this, I would start with a small program that did nothing but try to playback file to the external DAC over I2S... once that was working I'd glue that into the existing program.

Comment: @romkey The code above does not work. We are implementing a microphone and external DAC. We are using a library for Bluetooth that works great with the external DAC, but it no longer works when we integrate the microphone code. The issue is when we try to integrate the two. Each uses I2S_NUM_0 which is connected to the internal ADC. We thought we could use I2S_NUM_0 for the microphone still and use I2S_NUM_1 for the DAC, but it is not working.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Does the working code with the external DAC (and without the microphone code that breaks it) work if you change it to use I2S_NUM_1?

Comment: All good! When we run just the DAC code, it works fine with I2S_NUM_1. Thanks for this question. I hadn't thought about it. Will change how we continue, but still not sure why the two aren't working together. I would think NUM_0 and NUM_1 are independent from each other.